# Anular hover dentro de un hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

al hacer hover en una caja "#option" tengo que hacer que la sección cambie de background aleatoriamente(random), el problema que tengo que cuando estoy dentro de la caja y paso por los enlaces tb me hace el cambio de background, intente usar el pointer-events pero eso obviamente me inutiliza el click de los enlaces.

```
<section>
  <div id="option">
    <h2>Loren ipsum</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Loren ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Loren ipsum Loren ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Loren ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Loren ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Loren ipsum Loren ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Loren ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Podrias añadir tu codigo css para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como sólo pones el html, especificar si usas css o javascript y el código relevante es difícil ayudarte.

Aquí una forma de hacerlo con JavaScript:

```
optionDiv = document.getElementById('option');
optionDiv.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red');
optionDiv.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'inherit');
```

[Fiddle asociado](https://jsfiddle.net/fpuga/3fpyq5hu/5/).

Usamos `mouseenter/mouseleave` en lugar `mouseover/mouseout` para no capturar cada movimiento de ratón si no sólo cuando entra o sale del `div`. Y usamos `inherit` para volver al color que tenía originalmente. En caso de que tuviera aplicada alguna regla específica esta opción no valdría. Y tendríamos que almacenar el color en una variable antes de cambiarlo y luego restaurarlo o simplemente si sabemos el color aplicarlo en lugar de `inherit`

De todas formas para algo sencillo como esto lo mejor es usar directamente css:

```
#option:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[Fiddle asociado](https://jsfiddle.net/fpuga/3fpyq5hu/9/).

Comment: No hace falta colocar el código en jsfiddle, puedes usar los snipets de la pagina para mostrar código y hacerlo ejecutable, para mas información puedes revisar [¿Qué es Stack Snippet?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3292/qu%c3%a9-es-stack-snippet)

Comment: Perfecto, no sabia la diferencia entre los distintos mouseenter,leave,out,over. Me funciona bien ahora. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Gracias @the-breaker lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima